# Flutter paintZigZag

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Help me in drawing the zigZag line/border as show in the image at bottom. I found a zigzag paint function in flutter doc https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/paintZigZag.html but not sure how to use it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [CustomPaint()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) Widget.

Create your own CustomerPainter, say MyPainter, and place this in your widget tree:

```
CustomPaint(
    size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
    painter: MyPainter(),
),
```

The class MyPainter should extend [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) and also should override the paint() method which is where you specify the path to be painted on the canvas.

So you can just put the above 'paintZigZag' code there or call it like below along with appropriate parameters.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.blue;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill; 

    paintZigZag(canvas, paint, Offset(0, 100), Offset(200, 100), 100, 5);
  }

  void paintZigZag(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, Offset start, Offset end,
      int zigs, double width) {
    assert(zigs.isFinite);
    assert(zigs > 0);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(start.dx, start.dy);
    end = end - start;
    canvas.rotate(math.atan2(end.dy, end.dx));
    final double length = end.distance;
    final double spacing = length / (zigs * 2.0);
    final Path path = Path()..moveTo(0.0, 0.0);
    for (int index = 0; index < zigs; index += 1) {
      final double x = (index * 2.0 + 1.0) * spacing;
      final double y = width * ((index % 2.0) * 2.0 - 1.0);
      path.lineTo(x, y);
    }
    path.lineTo(length, 0.0);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```